# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server database I have dates in this format: `20110615`

I would like to display it this way `15.06.2011`

This is the code:

```
cast(convert((t4.DateOfBought, 7, 2), '. ', (t4.DateOfBought, 5, 2), '. ', left(t4.DateOfBought, 4)) as char charset cp1250) AS DateofBoughtUser,
```

and I got an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

Please help me what would be the correct format.

Thanks

Comment: What `(t4.DateOfBought,7,2)`  and `(t4.DateOfBought,5,2)` should mean?

Comment: jeez, what a mess of a query. You just need `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateOfBought,104)`

Comment: The best option would be to stop storing datetime values as strings. This is why there is a datetime datatype.

Comment: Please google and learn about the CONVERT function in SQL.   The first argument should be a datatype, not a column.   Were you trying to use a SUBSTRING function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(char(8), DateOfBought )), 104)
```